# How to Restore default action a key once we have prevented it?

Tags: javascript

The problem I am facing is that i have prevented the default action of a key in a function using `e.preventDefault();`.

Later when I am done with that function how can I restore the default action of that key?

Answer (score 0):

You could either remove your custom event handler or have a condition on it so that you don't prevent the default action once you no longer need it.